# Elasticsearch completion : strange behavior when multiple matches per document

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

When I use the completion type inside a suggest as described in the ElasticSearch documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-suggesters-completion.html), I do not manage to get all the matching words (I only get one matching word per document)

I test the following commands on my ElasticSearch 6.7.2 (which is the latest available on AWS at this moment) :

Deleting the index in case it exists

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X DELETE
```

Creating the index

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "page": {
      "properties": {
        "completion_terms": {
          "type": "completion"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Indexing a document

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test/_doc/1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT -d '
{
"completion_terms": ["restaurant", "restauration", "réseau"]
}'
```

Check the document exists

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test/_doc/1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Use the completion

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty=true" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "_source": ["suggestExact"],
  "suggest": {
      "suggestExact" : {
          "prefix" : "res",
          "completion" : {
              "field" : "completion_terms"
          }
      }
  }
}
'
```

The result is :

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "suggestExact" : [
      {
        "text" : "res",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 3,
        "options" : [
          {
            "text" : "restaurant",
            "_index" : "test",
            "_type" : "page",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : { }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**I'd like to get ALL the matching words (here, I get at most one result per document)**

In the example, "restauration" and "réseau" are missing

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

After many searches, I found that this is the intended behavior (that is to "suggest documents", instead of "suggest terms")

Especially, see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/31738

However, I still do not manage to achieve "suggest terms" even with the term suggester which seems to be the correct way (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-suggesters-term.html)